# How to iterate through Microsoft Exchange shared calendars in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exchange-server

Where I could find a code snippet which allows me to iterate through Appointments in a Exchange based system? The point is to check all the appointments in a given range of time and extrapolate some data to an Excel worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear when and where you need to run such code/task. The possible options are:

1. Automate Outlook to get all the required information from the user profile (mail profile). See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.
2. Use EWS (Exchange Web Services). See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.